# Could I return a class as return of a method?

Tags: asp.net, methods, types, reflection

My problem is,
I created a WebApi in asp.net. My models sent to my repository data from my class Person. But I want to persist in database in two different collections (I'm using MongoDB).

For this purpose I made an static method as it follows:

```
public static Type ReturnAsCollection(PersonTypeDelegate predicatee) 
        {

            if (predicatee.ToString().Equals(typeof(Infectados).Name.Substring(0)))
                return Type.GetType(typeof(Infectados).Name);
            else 
                return Type.GetType(typeof(Vacinados).Name);
        }
```

But the return is always null.

So, how could I return a Type in this case? There's another way to validate a class and throw it as a parameter?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, but you probably want to use generics instead. Also, why aren't you simply returning `typeof(...)`? Why try to get the type by name when you already know the type? Any why `Substring(0)`? that does nothing.

Comment: BTW, it's not normal in MongoDB to use collections like this - if you have a Person object and maybe a couple of classes inheriting from it, store them all in the person collection and let MongoDB's polymorphic serialization and deserialization code handle the rest.  https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/